# request.getHeader("referer") not working in HTTPS

Tags: java, spring, https

Can anyone please guide me how to fetch `request.getHeader("referer")` in HTTPS mode?

Currently it is returning null.

Comment: This [forms](http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/14b1961cwk/from-http-to-https-request-getheader-referer) fixing the issue

Answer (score 1):

> Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure) HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure protocol.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec15.html#sec15.1.3